# ¿Como actualizar django en visual studio?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

Hola a todos he instalado la version 2.0.2 de django y funciona bien,pero he notado que al crear un proyecto con visual studio me aparece la version 1.9, estoy muy confundido y tambien quisiera desarrollar un proyecto creado con cmd en visual studio que tan complicado es? normalmente corro mi proyecto con python manage.py runserver tal como lo indica la documentacion pero muchos hablan de virtualenv lo cual me confunde mas, que me recomiendan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Visual Studio es muy fácil, ya que simplifica todo.

Te recomiendo que descargues Visual Studio Community

Un virtualenv o entorno virtual de Python es un ambiente creado con el objetivo de aislar recursos como librerías y entorno de ejecución, del sistema principal o de otros entornos virtuales.

1.-Visual Studio te crea el virtualEnv e instala Django(Instala la versión más actual) cuando se crea el EntornoVirtual.

2.-Si requieres otra versión de Django puedes ir directamente a instalarlo desde el instalador de paquetes de Visual Studio.

3.-Te crea en automatico unas plantillas predeterminadas para que comiences con tu proyecto, el proyecto incluye un Log In

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen 5 esta el ejemplo para actualizar Django, seleccionas pip install Django==1.8 desde PyPi y empieza a descargar y reemplazar la versión que tengas, si quieres Django 2.0.2 pones Django==1.8 y el instalador va mostrar "pip install Django==1.8" desde PyPi, siempre y cuando la estructura de tu proyecto este basado en la misma estructura que genera Visual Studio.

En la imagen 6 estan los comandos para hacer las migraciones, o puedes hacerlo desde la consola que te da Visual Studio.

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations nombre-de-app
```

Comment: Que sucede si trabaje durante mucho tiempo con una version de django en un proyecto, sale una nueva version y la sintaxis cambia tendria que cambiar por mi cuenta linea por linea o visual haria ese cambio?

Comment: De hecho si tendrias que cambiar algunas lineas o la otra sería que instales la versión de Django que necesitas, aunque también podria funcionar que hagas un  nuevo entorno Virtual y en este instales la versión antigua de Django con la cual funciona tu proyecto

Comment: Y en el entorno Virtual que te crea Vstudio por default tener la versión actual de Django, aunque no lo he intentado hacer de esa forma, pero ahí es donde entra el poder de un EntornoVirtual

Comment: Entonces tendrías 2 entornos 1 con la versión que funciona tu proyecto y el otro entorno con la versión nueva de django

Comment: También tendrias que ver como ramifica Visual Studio los directorios de los statics files, settings etc
Ya que si hiciste tu aplicación usando Sublime Text entonces es posible que no tengas ramificada tus carpetas
a como las crea Visual Studio

Comment: Pues logre hacer funcionar hace unos instantes mi proyecto creado con editores de texto en visual studio, solo cree un proyecto con el mismo nombre, oye pero el cmbio de version a django al parecer solo afecta al proyecto actual pero creo uno nuevo siempre me sale una versiona antigua, de todas formas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si solo al proyecto actual que tengas abierto en visual Studio y que por ende tiene creado un entorno virtual